# Custom Thank You page redirect based on product variation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have a code that works great to redirect to a custom Thank You page after purchasing any product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'updated_redirectcustom');
 
function updated_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = '/thank-you/';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I decided to implement a custom redirect to another page for a couple of specific product variations, but, unfortunately, the code that I changed does not work and all orders are still redirected to the /thank-you/ URL:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'updated_redirectcustom');
 
function updated_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = '/thank-you/';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
    if( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // False
        $redirection = false;
            
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
            // Product ID(s)
            $product_ids = array( $item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id() );
                    
            // Product ID in array
            if ( in_array( 12345, 123456, $product_ids ) ) {
                $redirection = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $redirection ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/thank-you-2/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As finally you are comparing 2 arrays, use instead `array_intersect()`, replacing this code line:

```
if ( in_array( 12345, 123456, $product_ids ) ) {
```

with:

```
if ( count( array_intersect( array(12345, 123456), $product_ids ) ) > 0 ) {
```

Now it should work for all product types, including variations.

Also to shorten the loop, you should add a `break;` below `$redirection = true;` (optional).

Comment: Dont you need count for that ? Like if (count(array_intersect([12345, 123456], $product_ids)) > 0) { } i think in case array is empty will not work wihtout count or check if array is not empty first ?

Comment: @Snuffy Oups, hopefully you got this… thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the usage of the in_array() function. The function expects the first parameter to be the search value, and the second parameter to be the array to search in. However, in your code, you have provided the search value as the second parameter and two integers as the first parameter. Here's the corrected code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'updated_redirectcustom' );

function updated_redirectcustom( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = '/thank-you/';

    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }

    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $redirection = false;

        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
            $product_ids = array( $item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id() );

            if ( in_array( 12345, $product_ids ) || in_array( 123456, $product_ids ) ) {
                $redirection = true;
                break; // Exit the loop if a match is found
            }
        }

        if ( $redirection ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/thank-you-2/' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately, this code doesn't work as well since the 12345 ids are ids for the product ID and not for variation. And that's my problem

Comment: This answer is most likely ChatGPT